# spark groupby on several columns at same time

Tags: apache-spark

I’m using Spark2.0
I have a dataframe  having several columns like id, latitude, longitude, time,
I want to do a groupby and keep [“latitude”,” longitude”] always together,

Could I do the following?

```
df.groupBy('id',[“latitude”,” longitude”] ,'time')
```

I want to calculate records number for each user , at each different time,  with each different location  [“latitude”,” longitude”].

Comment: What do you mean "always together"?

Comment: Please add an example input with expected output.

Comment: I want to calculate records number for each user , at each different time,  with each different location  [“latitude”,” longitude”].

Answer (score 1):

You can combine "latitude" and "longitude" columns and then can use `groupBy`. Below sample is using Scala.

```
val df = Seq(("1","33.33","35.35","8:00"),("2","31.33","39.35","9:00"),("1","33.33","35.35","8:00")).toDF("id","latitude","longitude","time")
df.show()
val df1 = df.withColumn("lat-long",array($"latitude",$"longitude"))
df1.show()
val df2 = df1.groupBy("id","lat-long","time").count()
df2.show()
```

Output will be like below.

```
+---+--------------+----+-----+
| id|      lat-long|time|count|
+---+--------------+----+-----+
|  2|[31.33, 39.35]|9:00|    1|
|  1|[33.33, 35.35]|8:00|    2|
+---+--------------+----+-----+
```

Comment: This might be a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
df.groupBy('id', 'latitude', 'longitude','time').agg(...)
```

This will work as expected without any additional steps.